# Codeigniter - check if user is logged and exists (it's a real user)

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, session, logging

I'm trying to set session data for users when they log in to my website.

So if the user exists in db, I set a session data like : `$this->session->set_userdata('user_exists','1');`

Now every time i want to check if user exists and is logged i do:

```
if($this->session->userdata('user_exists')){
 //do somenthing for logged user
}
```

Now I'm wondering if this means that user is logged and exists in the database since he logged and I set him a session param, is this true? Or I'll get security problems?

NB: I'm using session database

Comment: yeah it's fine but encrypt your session by enabling config.php file. Also add some length values to identify the session

Comment: @Sundar yep already using encryption key, so checking if that session data exists is the same as checking if the user is in db and so i can avoid one more query to find user in db?

Comment: @Sundar if you sure put that as an answer i'll accept

Comment: your answer is correct nothing to add.. You are right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

//session encryption is mandatory

```
  $sess_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

   if(!empty($sess_id))
   {
        redirect(site_url().'/reports');

   }else{

        $this->session->set_userdata(array('msg'=>'')); 
        //load the login page
        $this->load->view('login/index');        
   }
```

Comment: i think !empty() is useless cause session -> userdata return false or data ;)

Comment: yes.. empty(0) will always gives true. So both are equal empty(1) is false