# How to disable going back to login page after i loggedin

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to prevent the user to go back after i logged in, how can i do that.. please help im using php and codeigniter

I have this code on my controller

```
function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

    if ($this->session->userdata('LoggedIn') == FALSE) 
    {
      session_destroy();
      redirect('login','refresh');
    }

  }
```

I am open to all your help and suggestions guys

Comment: you should set your user data to session then create a condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - check if user is logged and exists (it's a real user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543509/codeigniter-check-if-user-is-logged-and-exists-its-a-real-user)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($this->session->userdata('LoggedIn') == TRUE) 
{
   redirect('dashboard');
}
```

**Place this in your index function on login controller.**

Comment: I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like as below

```
function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

    if ($this->session->userdata('LoggedIn') == FALSE) 
    {
      session_destroy();
      redirect('login','refresh');
    }else{
      redirect('home','refresh');
    }

  }
```

Comment: what the foolishness is this..if your are access a function in loginController after login ,constructor invoke in each call and redirect it to redirect control to dashboard,other functions are not work in proper!

Answer (score 0):

Add below code on your login page controller, So if user came back, It will redirect again.

```
if ($this->session->userdata('LoggedIn') == TRUE) 
{
  redirect('homepage');//Your page after login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean after successful login ,user not allow to load login page again!

So you want to check each login function call the user is exists or not

```
function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
   if ($this->session->userdata('LoggedIn') == FALSE) 
   {
      session_destroy();
      redirect('LoginPage','refresh');
   }
}

    function yourLoginfun()
      {
        $LoggedIn = $this->session->userdata('LoggedIn');

       if(!empty($LoggedIn))
       {
            redirect('/user_homepage.php', 'refresh');
       }
      else
         {
           $this->load->view('LoginPage');
         }
    }
```